# Change src dynamically and change the image with javascript

Tags: javascript

Codigo HTML

```
<img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice">
```

Codigo Javascript

```
// Display the result
var diceDom = document.querySelector('.dice');
diceDom.style.display = 'block';
diceDom.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';
```

Comment: There is no question here. Be more clear on what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Hi I'm new I need to change the src of the image dynamically the files were in local but I uploaded the images to a server and I need to get the images changed dynamically with each iteration is a game that I have in javascript, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even your question is not clear, But I assume that u want to change image at a point use javascript.

your code should be work correctly if "dice-"+dice+".png" can find in server.

Comment: if I want to change the image but the files were in the root of the folder but I uploaded the project to codepen and it does not allow me to upload them because I have a free account so I can not host files that do not have an html extension css and js, I uploaded the files to an image server to perform the same operation but bringing the files from an external server. Is now clear

Comment: @wildsrincon Have u think about use base64 format for image?